# href and onclick

Tags: javascript

I have 2 requirements:

1. There are some messages and i have to navigate through these
   messages on tab out, i.e if i click
   tab the control should move from one
   message to another and so on, All
   the messages should be links.

   This can be doing by using href.
2. If i click on these messages a function is called which actually sets the focus for the corresponding field. like if i have a name field and if i enter number a error message comes and clicking on this message the control goes to the corresponding field.

i added a href: javascript (function) in anchor tag

this works properly in IE7, but it doesnt work in IE6 i get a new window opened with true or false value. If i use onclick and remove href it works properly in IE6 but the navigation doesnt happen.

Is there any other alternative where both the navigation and onclick works or something else needs to be added.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Regds
viswa

Comment: The specific problem isn't very clear.  Can you point us to a simplified example showing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Say for example:

<a href="javascript:fnselectfield()"> abc </a>

If i use similar type of code, navigation happens through href and onclicking the link the function is called and validation takes place. This similar code doesnt work in ie6 and onclick needs to be used instead of href. 

I think it will be clear now by the example given above.

Answer (score 2):

Try returning `false` in the links' href attributes, or using an '#null'. Bottom line, you should not get rid of the `href` for anchor tags as they will no longer be navigable via the tab key:

```
<a href="javascript:return false" onclick="doSomething()">Foo</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="#null" onclick="doSomething()">Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider not using using an anchor tag.  Anchor tags should be reserved for Navigation.

Have you thought of the <**label**> tag?

```
<label for="foo">This is Foo</label>
<input type="text" id="foo" value="" />
```

Clicking on the label will give the input the focus.

Answer (score 1):

You could use unobtrusive JS rather than inline, then you just need the href.

```
<a href="/foo" class="fooLink">Foo</a>
```

The in a document ready function (Assuming you're using jQuery, can be easily changed to Prototype or vanilla js)

```
  $(".fooLink").click(function() {
     doSomething();
  });
```